# Capturar horario local do visitante

Tags: php, datetime, data, ip

Ola,por motivos de segurança preciso pegar o horário em que o visitante da pagina entrou, mas o sistema aparentemente esta pegando horário do servidor.

IP: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Data: [03-07-2017 - 14:05:49]
(Horario local 11:05)

Estou usando o seguinte código

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$data = date("d-m-Y - H:i:s");
```

Oque eu poderia usar para pegar o horário do Brasil(Horário oficial de Brasilia) ?

Comment: Primeiramente você deve entender que os métodos apresentados são executados no servidor, isto é, retornará informações do servidor.

Para questões de segurança você deve realmente capturar a data do servidor sim, afinal o destino é o mesmo. Acredito que o correto seja sincronizar o relógio do servidor, até por que é de se esperar que o horário do lado do cliente pode não ser o mesmo com os demais clientes.

Comment: Que segurança maluca é essa que depende de um dado arbitrário facilmente falsificável pelo usuário?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente o horário do log é o do próprio servidor, como disse @Diego Vieira vários usuários podem ter horários diferentes, mas respondendo a sua pergunta

> Oque eu poderia usar para pegar o horário do Brasil(Horário oficial de Brasilia) ?

Caso queria apenas uma data especifica em outro timezone, o de São Paulo por exemplo

```
$dt = new DateTime('now',new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y - H:i:s');
```

Ou pode-se usar a função date_default_timezone_set para definir o timezone default da aplicação

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```